# Delete Core Data Entry from Table View Controller

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7

I am trying to delete a core data entry from my table view controller, so that when I swipe left, a delete button comes up and deletes the entry. Unfortunately, I am getting the error: "Property 'Classes' not found on type "ClassTableViewController *" on line 251 and 260 (code posted below) and am not sure what to do. I have a NSMutableObject class called Classes.m and Classes.h, and they have been imported, but Xcode doesn't seem to recognize it.

Here is the code:

ClassTableViewController.m

```
#import "ClassTableViewController.h"
#import "Classes.m"
#import "Classes.h"
#import "ClassTableViewCell.h"
#import "NewClassViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface ClassTableViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(ClassTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation ClassTableViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Segue

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowClass"] ){
        NewClassViewController *dvc = (NewClassViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Classes *classID = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [dvc setClassID:classID];

    } else if  ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addClass"]) {
        NewClassViewController *dvc = (NewClassViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [dvc setClassID:[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyClassesID" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    }

}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(firstDone)];

    if (_managedObjectContext == nil)
    {
        _managedObjectContext = [(ClassTableViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  _managedObjectContext);
    }


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void) firstDone {

    [self.navigationController  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ClassesCell";

    ClassTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ClassTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate


- (void)configureCell:(ClassTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Classes *classID = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.classLabel.text = classID.classTitle;
    cell.periodLabel.text = classID.period;
}



#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyClassesID" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    assert(self.managedObjectContext);

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"period" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
   [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;


}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.Classes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.Classes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

The code in which I am receiving the error:

Line 251:

```
    [context deleteObject:[self.Classes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Line 260:

```
    [self.Classes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: can you put code for `ClassTableViewController.h`?

Comment: This is an unreasonable quantity of code for a question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, remove #import "Classes.m". Second, I assume self.Classes is an array, which raises two questions:

1. If your class is named `Classes`, then why is your variable named `Classes` as well? Rename the variable to `vClasses` or `aClasses` or `classes`. Also, make sure that `self.classes` (or in yourcase `self.Classes`) is being initialized properly. Debug!
2. Why are you using an array for `Classes` objects, when you have `NSFetchedResultsController` setup? You should use `self.fetchedResultsController` instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This are all excellent points and should help you debug the issue.

Comment: I'm not using self.Classes as an array, but rather an NSMutableObject so that it deletes. This is my first time I'm trying this so I'm not exactly sure how this works. I tried changing it to self.NSFetchedResultsController, but I got the error: 
No visible @interface for 'NSFetchedResultsController' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex'

Comment: I think what you need to do, before anything else, is to read about NSArray, NSMutableArray, NSFetchedResultsController, UITableView, UIViewController, and UITableViewController. Your questions suggest that you need to learn the basics. Try online blogs, a book on iOS application development, OR (recommended) check Stanford Lectures (free), or iPhone Development Videos by Apple on iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, there is no property named "Classes" in this class, sure you imported the class named Classes, but it is not a property/instance variable. At least not that I see...

```
[self.Classes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This line doesn't make sense, you should be telling your data source to remove the object...